# ChannelMergerNode in Web audio API not merging channels

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use the web audio API to create an audio stream with the left and right channels generated with different oscillators. The output of the left channel is correct, but the right channel is 0. Based on the spec, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Tested in Chrome dev.

Code:

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var l_osc = context.createOscillator();
l_osc.type = "sine";
l_osc.frequency.value = 100;
var r_osc = context.createOscillator();
r_osc.type = "sawtooth";
r_osc.frequency.value = 100;
// Combine the left and right channels.
var merger = context.createChannelMerger(2);
merger.channelCountMode = "explicit";
merger.channelInterpretation = "discrete";
l_osc.connect(merger, 0, 0);
r_osc.connect(merger, 0, 1);
var dest_stream = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
merger.connect(dest_stream);
// Dump the generated waveform to a MediaStream output.
l_osc.start();
r_osc.start();
var track = dest_stream.stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
var plugin = document.getElementById('plugin');
plugin.postMessage(track);
```

Comment: Created a JSFiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/notthetup/0x11erbb/

Comment: Seems like its something to do with the channelCountMode. Not setting it to 'explicit' seems to fix it. But I am not sure why.

Comment: Removing channelCountMode works. Thanks.

Comment: But I am not sure why it's so. The default channelCount is 2. So even if you put it as explicit, and don't set the channelCount, it should up-merge to stereo. Bug?

Answer (score 1):

The channelInterpretation means the merger node will mix the stereo oscillator connections to two channels each - but then because you have an explicit channelCountMode, it's stacking the two-channels-per-connection to get four channels and (because it's explicit) just dropping the top two channels.  Unfortunately the second two channels are the two channels from the second input - so it loses all channels from the second connection.

In general, you shouldn't need to mess with the channelCount interpretation stuff, and it will do the right thing for stereo.

Comment: I don't quite understand. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#OscillatorNode, the output of each oscillator is mono, not stereo. So the two mono channel should be stacked resulting in a stereo output. When I didn't set channelInterpretation, it upmixed one of the oscillators into both output channels, so I was getting identical data in both output channels.

Comment: The problem is that the default channelCount for nodes is 2 - so the Merger's inputs are causing the upmixing from the mono output of the oscillator to stereo, then there are four inputs.  Try setting the channelCount on the Merger to 1.

Comment: I get it, thanks. I thought channelCount applied to the outputs, but the spec says it's for inputs. I guess I should have read the spec more carefully.

Comment: It's not crystal-clear. I always found the connections vs channels model tough to keep in my head at one time.  I think merger should probably be channelcount 1, though, by default.

Comment: Actually, you just shouldn't be setting the channelcountmode to explicit, unless you're trying to force the inputs to mono.